# Blender Scripting: ERROR: too much data in this layer, compared to elements in mesh, skipping!

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, import, .fbx

I am working on a Blender script that does rendering of FBX file based on the software it was originally generated in Eg. 3D Max, CLO, AutoCAD etc. The script works perfect for all the FBX other than the one generated by CLO. I get following error

`ERROR: too much data in this layer, compared to elements in mesh, skipping!`

I did try `bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=file_input, use_custom_props=False)` but no success!

Can someone help me to understand what this error mean and what would be solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error handling was originally introduced in commit [rBAde7d0111100f](https://developer.blender.org/rBAde7d0111100f33ecdae039ea218201b4230038b0) as a fix for [T43718](https://developer.blender.org/T43718). This issue appears to be that the file contains more entries in the FBX layer data than there are elements of e.g. vertices, edges, polygons or polyloops. If the handling of the FBX importer is correct, then this is an improperly written FBX file. Blender will try to skip the wrongly formatted data.

You should check if CLO has released an update that fixes the issue and if not, export to a different format. If they provide a way to report bugs I would suggest you contact them so that they are aware of the issue.